# Facebook share count - how many distinct user have shared

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I am looking for a way to find out how many unique user have shared a page on facebook. With the following URL i already get a lot of information:

[Facebook Counts](http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&format=json&urls=http://www.stackoverflow.com)

But it does not tell me if the page was shared thousands of times by one user or one time by thousands of users.

Any help to get this information would be highly appreciated!

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no endpoint where you get user counts on URL shares. If you own a Facebook Page, and want to get insights about certain posts, you can use the `/{post_id}/insights` edge.

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/insights
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/insights#page_stories

Remember, you'll need the `read_insights` for that.

Another option might be `/{object-id}/sharedposts`, found at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/sharedposts

You'll need `read_stream` permission.

Additionally, the old REST API will be finally deprecated:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#restapiv21